# maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module StrictDuplicateCode

Tags: java, maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

That's the full error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (default) on project abc-123-micro-service: Failed during checkstyle configuration: cannot initialize module StrictDuplicateCode - Unable to instantiate 'StrictDuplicateCode' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as .StrictDuplicateCode, StrictDuplicateCodeCheck, .StrictDuplicateCodeCheck. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly. -> [Help 1]
```

My maven configuration for checkstyle plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>8.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My checkstyle.xml config file doesn't contain any of the 'duplicate' rules mentioned in the error. How can I fix this problem and let all the checks pass?

EDIT: 
The contents of checkstyle.xml: https://pastebin.com/kuJAFiiP

Comment: Good suggestion, but in my pom.xml there is only one configLocation. Could it be that there is some default config applied by maven-checkstyle-plugin? However I know for sure that my custom checkstyle.xml is applied, because when I change its name to checkstyle1.xml, then there is an error that the file is not found.

Comment: I think the problem is somehow related to the version conflict between maven-checkstyle-plugin and checkstyle dependency. changing the version 8.8 to a much earlier version gets me another error.

Comment: The [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html) say `configuration` should go directly under `plugin`, don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: @ThomasJensen putting the configuration under plugin has fixed the problem! Thanks! 
The docs here are wrong then? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/usage.html. There in the bottom example, **configuration** is under **execution**.

Comment: @ThomasJensen Do you wanna post the right answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `cannot initialize module StrictDuplicateCode` indicates that Checkstyle fails to initialize a check that it found while traversing the config file. Also, the *StrictDuplicateCode* check was [removed](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.2) in Checkstyle 6.2.

Now since your config file does not reference this check, it must be that the Maven Checkstyle Plugin reads some other config file. [Its docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html) say that `configuration` should go directly under `plugin`. Try moving the `configuration` XML element up.

Answer (score 1):

It means StrictDuplicateCodeCheck is not supported.

You can edit the config file checkstyle.xml to remove this check.

**Update:**

Sample simple config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        <module name="AvoidStarImport"/>
        <module name="ConstantName"/>
        <module name="EmptyBlock"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

**Update 2:**

Verify the location of checkstyle.xml. It probably should be in the project root.

**Update 3:**

Glad you already found the solution. Here is the pom file, for reference.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>clucinvt</groupId>
    <artifactId>s02checkstyle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question: "My checkstyle.xml config file doesn't contain any of the 'duplicate' rules mentioned in the error. ".
checkstyle.xml doesn't contain StrictDuplicateCodeCheck.

Comment: Please post content of checkstyle.xml

Comment: A few different modules are using this class StrictDuplicateCode, e.g. EmptyLineSeparator. I'd recommend start from a simple config, and gradually add more checks from there. See my updated answer for a sample config.

Comment: Well, the error message is used when it fails to initialize a *Check*, not when it fails to find a required class.

Comment: @CInvt did not help using this simple config. getting the same error.

Comment: Should probably update pom.xml, because it still looks like the old one, not the fixed one. Configuration tag should be directly under the plugin tag.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the version to 3.1.0 from 3.0.0 and it worked for me.

maven-checkstyle-plugin
3.1.0

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If someone still facing this issue - try to check your JAVA_HOME path. In my case, JRE was used instead of JDK. When I fixed it - issue with the maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check has gone

Answer (score 0):

i faced similar issue, i changed the version of org.apache.maven.plugins plugns from 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 in pom.xml
and used clean install -Dcheckstyle.skip as the command for generating the jar from eclipse it worked for me.